# Visual Studio add-in hook on solution load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hook, solution

I'm trying to write an add-in for Visual Studio that needs to be run every time a solution is loaded. Eventually I hope to make it a solution add-in so that it only runs for solutions that need it, but I'm wondering if there's any way to have my add-in hook on the user loading a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VCProjectEngineEvents` `SolutionLoaded` event.

Edit: I can only hope somebody else can come up with a sample they can post -- the only relevant code I have is something I can't post.

Comment: That's great! I'm a bit unfamiliar to C#, though, so could I possibly trouble you for an example of how you register a hook? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Saver add-in source code](http://www.tabsstudio.com/download/addins/Saver_100.zip) as an example (it is an add-in for the Tabs Studio add-in):
In Saver.cs you subscribe for events:

```
solutionEventsSink = new SolutionEventsSink(orderController);
System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(dte as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);
vsSolution = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsSolution)) as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution;
vsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents(solutionEventsSink, out sinkCookie);
```

In SolutionEventsSink.cs are actual solution events handlers:

```
class SolutionEventsSink : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolutionEvents
```